# output from different models in Django

Tags: python, django-models

I'm new in Django. And I have a problem((I can't display fields from different models. A lot of time was executed, but don't understand.
Here is my code.
This is my models:

```
from django.db import models

class Abonent(models.Model):
    osrah = models.IntegerField(db_column='Osrah', primary_key=True)  
    pib = models.CharField(db_column='PIB', max_length=70) 
    adress = models.CharField(db_column='Adress', max_length=70) 
    meter = models.IntegerField(db_column='Meter') 
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % (self.pib)

class Oplata(models.Model):
    abonent = models.ForeignKey(Abonent, db_column=False, blank=True, 
                          null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idoplata = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    saldo = models.FloatField()
    idstala = models.IntegerField(db_column='idStala') 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % ( self.saldo,)




class Rahunok(models.Model):
    abonent = models.ForeignKey(Abonent, blank=True, null=True, 
                                default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idrahunok = models.AutoField(db_column='idRahunok', primary_key=True) 
    idstala = models.IntegerField(db_column='idStala')  
    datarah = models.DateField(db_column='dataRah') 
    pokaz1 = models.FloatField()
    pokaz2 = models.FloatField()
    spozkwt = models.FloatField(db_column='SpozKWT') 
    spozuah = models.FloatField(db_column='SpozUAH') 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)




    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rahunok'
```

And this my url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from abonent.models import Abonent,Oplata


urlpatterns = [


    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=Abonent.objects.all(),
                                            template_name="abonent/abonents.html")),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model=Abonent,
                                             template_name='abonent/persons.html')),
```

it's my person.html:

```
{% extends "mainApp/wrapper.html"%}

{% block content %}


        <h2 class="text-info">{{ abonent.pib }}</h2>
        <h2 class="text-info">{{ abonent.oplata.saldo }}</h2>
        <h2 class="text-info">{{ abonent.oplata_set.idstala}}</h2>
        <h5 class=" text-info">{{ abonent.adress }}</h5>

{% endblock %}
```

From model Abonent picks out everything, and doesn't want from Oplata.
What is the problem?
Would be very grateful if someone helps.

Comment: Please add the view files.

Answer (score 0):

Django's `DetailView` by default puts the object in a key called `object`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Insert the single object into the context dict.
    """
    context = {}
    if self.object:
        context['object'] = self.object
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
        if context_object_name:
            context[context_object_name] = self.object
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super(SingleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

As you can see, you now have the object in context as the key `object`

Change your template to the following to make it work:

```
{% extends "mainApp/wrapper.html"%}

{% block content %}


        <h2 class="text-info">{{ object.pib }}</h2>
        <h2 class="text-info">{{ object.oplata.saldo }}</h2>
        <h2 class="text-info">{{ object.oplata_set.idstala}}</h2>
        <h5 class=" text-info">{{ object.adress }}</h5>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for quickly answer!

Comment: Works the same way

Comment: From the Abonent model everything comes true, but no Oplata

Comment: And I don't have views.py

Comment: What does your detail page look like. Can you link a screenshot